# How can i increment +1 to the value in database using update

Tags: mysql

Here i am trying to increment the value in database by + 1.for example
here in database i have value 3 in one column by name `owners` now when i call the below function. i want to increment the column by +1  i.e the column value now should become 4

```
function updateOwners($product_id){
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "UPDATE product_list set product_current_co_owners =  where product_id ='$product_id'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    /*if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<b>Total co-owners:</b><br><span>'.$row["product_co_owners"].'</span>';
        }
    } else {
        echo "No data available";
    }*/
    $conn->close();
}
```

how can i do this?

```
$sql = "UPDATE product_list set product_current_co_owners =# here i want add +1 to previous value  where product_id ='$product_id'";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add +1 to the previous value like

```
UPDATE product_list 
set product_current_co_owners = product_current_co_owners + 1 
where product_id ='$product_id';
```

Comment: But its adding +2. when i have 1 in value and call function. the value becomes 3

Comment: @MithunRaikar, that's not possible unless you are calling the function twice or if there is a trigger defined which is doing this trick. Check and confirm the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this but your column must be integer type

```
UPDATE product_list set product_current_co_owners =product_current_co_owners+1  where product_id ='$product_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "UPDATE product_list set product_current_co_owners =  owners + 1 where product_id ='$product_id'";
```